# scrollToRowAtIndexPath using subclassed UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell that contains two TextFields, I would like to know how I could use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`from my subclass?

I have set up the UITextField Delegate I just dont know how to then send the message back to the original ViewController to action the UITableViewRow to scroll up above the Keyboard.

```
subclasscell.h

@interface CustomFinishingCell : UITableViewCell

subclasscell.m

cell.heightTextField.delegate = self;
cell.widthTextField.delegate = self;


callingclass.m
//cellForRow
cell.heightTextField.text = heightString;

//textFieldShouldBeginEditing, action scroller here...
```

So I am not really sure how to access the textfieldshouldbeginediting from the subclassed cell class so that I can scroll the tableviewcell above the keyboard when a UItextField is pressed.

Comment: Either you add a property containing your viewcontroller to your CustomFinishingCell or you try to set the UITextFieldDelegate of your textfields to your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a custom data in cell to identify the cell and viewController can use it to find the cell's indexPath.

Create a protocol for your cell and make your viewController implement it.

like

```
@protocol YourDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)textFieldGetResponderIn:(CustomFinishingCell *)cell ;
@end
```

when textfieldshouldbeginediting is called , call the [delegate textFieldGetResponderIn:self] ;

You make implement your cell like this:

```
@protocol YourDelegate ;

@interface CustomFinishingCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<YourDelegate> delegate ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id customeData ;

@end


@protocol YourDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)textFieldGetResponderIn:(CustomFinishingCell *)cell ;
@end
```

Comment: This is the way. Store the indexPath when you recycle/create cell

Comment: okay going to try this.. bit confused but will hard a hard think about it.

Comment: so do i create that delegate inside the viewcontroller? or inside the customFinishingCell? at the moment I am getting errors from (CustomFinishingCell *), it says Expected a type? I have thiin my CustomFinishingCell header file.

Comment: thanks so much for the update, going to check it out now. is abit clearer now so i should go okay with it.. going to crank it now and will let you know how i go.